# Rails, JS: How to associate files attached through javascript to a model before model is created? (using Redactor)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, redactor

I set up wysiwyg editor, [redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) in my rails app. It allows attachments to be uploaded to s3. Redactor sends the attachment file to a controller I set up that uploads the file to s3 and responds with the url in json. Redactor then takes the json response and adds it as a link to the file within the editor.

Unfortunately at this point it does not associate the attachment with the model, it only adds the url to the content. Is there a way to associate it to the attachment? The issue with setting up the relationship in the uploading controller is that the object has not been created yet. Would it make sense to use redactor's uploadsuccessful javascript callback to add a hidden input field with the url and then associate it with the model in the create action?

controller upload function: I'm using carrierwave for the uploads

```
def attachment_upload
    uploader = StepAttachmentUploader.new
    uploader.store!(params[:file])
    render json: { filelink: uploader.url, filename: params[:file].original_filename }
end
```